How to prove the posterior probability for multivariate case (i.e. dimension $d\ge 2$)?
Suppose there are $k$ groups, $\pi_1, \pi_2, \cdots, \pi_k$, with the probability density function for group $\pi_i$ being $f_i(\boldsymbol{x})$, where $\boldsymbol x\in R^d$. The prior probability that a sample $\boldsymbol{x}$ belongs to group $\pi_i$ is denoted as $p_i$, where $i=1,2, \cdots, k$, and it satisfies the condition that $p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_k=1$. Employing Bayesian theory, one can prove that the posterior probability (i.e., the probability that the sample $\boldsymbol{x}$ belongs to $\pi_i$ given that $\boldsymbol{x}$ is known) of $\boldsymbol{x}$ belonging to $\pi_i$ is calculated as
$$
P\left(\pi_i \mid \boldsymbol{x}\right)=\frac{p_i f_i(\boldsymbol{x})}{\sum_{j=1}^k p_j f_j(\boldsymbol{x})}, \quad i=1,2, \cdots, k. \tag{1}
$$
When $d=1$, from the Bayes' Formula

Theorem  (Bayes' Formula) If the events $A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_n$ are mutually exclusive and $B$ is a subset of their union, $\bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j$, then when $P(B)>0$, it holds that
$$
P\left(A_j \mid B\right)=\frac{P\left(A_j\right) P\left(B \mid A_j\right)}{\sum_{i=1}^n P\left(A_i\right) P\left(B \mid A_i\right)}, \quad 1 \leq j \leq n.
$$

we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
P\left(\pi_i \mid x\right) & =\lim _{\Delta x \rightarrow 0+} P\left(\pi_i \mid x<X \leqslant x+\Delta x\right)=\lim _{\Delta x \rightarrow 0+} \frac{P\left(\pi_i\right) P\left(x<X \leqslant x+\Delta x \mid \pi_i\right)}{\sum_{j=1}^k P\left(\pi_j\right) P\left(x<X \leqslant x+\Delta x \mid \pi_j\right)} \\
& =\lim _{\Delta x \rightarrow 0+} \frac{p_i \int_x^{x+\Delta x} f_i(t) \mathrm{d} t / \Delta x}{\sum_{j=1}^k p_j \int_x^{x+\Delta x} f_j(t) \mathrm{d} t / \Delta x}=\frac{p_i f_i(x)}{\sum_{j=1}^k p_j f_j(x)}, \quad i=1,2, \cdots, k
\end{aligned}
$$
How to prove (1) when $d\ge 2$?

$(1)$ has nothing to do with $d:$ there isn't anything left to prove.

Bayes Theorem is agnostic to the dimension of random variables involved, so the resulting expression is the same for $x\in\mathbb{R}^d,, d\geq 2$.

@JohandeAguas Bayes theorem is about discrete propositions and PMFs. OP is asking about PDFs on continuous variables.

@Feri That's up to interpretation: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bayes%27_theorem#For_continuous_random_variables
